# Azure Bot Framework - Wrap card action and button text

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, adaptive-cards

I’m having an issue where buttons and actions in hero and adaptive cards won’t wrap text. I have searched the internet and everyone is mentioning a webchat.js and botchat.js files that can be adjusted to fix this. I can’t seem to find those in my code. Has the name changed? I know botchat was changed to webchat. Would anyone happen to know where to fix this in the **Basic Bot NodeJS implementation SDK V4**?

Comment: What channel do you need this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using webchat, you could use plain css. This worked for me:

```
  .ac-pushButton > div {
    white-space: normal !important;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find an answer in node_modules > wordwrap. There is a function that you can call in there to wrap any text you'd like. Thank you @Hessel for the help.

var wrap = require('wordwrap')(70);
return CardFactory.heroCard(
                '',
                answer,
                CardFactory.images([]),
                CardFactory.actions([
                    {
                        type: 'postBack',
                        title: wrap(YOUR_TEXT),
                        value: YOUR_VALUE
                    }
                ])
            );

Comment: Nice. Would be great if share how to do that in webchat. I am looker for a nicer solution that css

Comment: @Hessel this is what I used.